# Prove that: if $\pi(m)\pi(m-2)-\pi^2(m-1)=0$, then $m \ne prime$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

This is not a great way of testing for a prime number, $P_n$.

Where $\pi(m)$ is the prime counting function.

Let $m=2k+1$ where $k=1,2,3,4,...$

if $\pi(m)\pi(m-2)-\pi^2(m-1)=0$, then $m$ is not a prime number.$\tag1 $
if $\pi(m)\pi(m-2)-\pi^2(m-1)=n$, then $m$ is a prime number. $\tag2$
where $P_{n+1}=m$

---

How can you show that this conjecture, $(1)$ is correct?

examples:

$\pi(m)\pi(m-2)-\pi^2(m-1)=0$, $m \ne prime$

$\pi(15)\pi(13)-\pi^2(14)=0$, $15 \ne prime$

$\pi(25)\pi(23)-\pi^2(24)=0$, $25 \ne prime$

$\pi(123)\pi(123)-\pi^2(122)=0$, $123 \ne prime$

Of course if this conjecture $(1)$ is correct, we wouldn't use it to test for prime number, that would be madness!

Comment: (ignore the case $m=3$ for what follows):  If $m$ is prime then $m-1$ is not, so $\pi(m-2)=\pi(m-1)=p(m)-1$.  In that case your equation would be $x(x-1)-(x-1)^2= 0 \implies x=x-1$.

Comment: Typo:  In the above I wrote $p(m)$ for $\pi(m)$ in one spot.

Comment: I am asking a trivial question right? I am very clueless to this knowledge of prime number. I was just messing around with wolfram calculator and spotted the formula.

Comment: The claims follow directly from the definitions, but there's nothing wrong with working examples and trying to spot patterns.

Comment: In fact , we trivially have for every integer $m$ : $\pi(m-1)=\pi(m)$ if and only if $m$ is not prime , so knowing $\pi(m-1)$ and $\pi(m)$ would immediately (without even computing any expression) tell us whether $m$ is prime.

Answer (score 1):

Proof by contradiction: Per your starting conditions, $m$ is odd. Assume $m=p_n$ is the $n$th prime. Let's look first at the case $m>3$. Then $\pi(m)=n\ge 3$ but $\pi(m-1)=\pi(m-2)=n-1$ because there is one fewer prime ($p_n$ itself), but no more than one fewer prime. The next smaller prime must be $\le p_n-2$, which is not eliminated from the count $\pi(m-2)$.

$n\ge 3 \Rightarrow n(n-1)-(n-1)^2\ne 0$.

So if $m>3$ is prime, the difference of products cannot be $0$

The case $m=3$ is readily excluded by examination, since $\pi(1)=0$.